# How do you display image objects in a Django template using a custom template tag? (coding included)

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I have the following code that fails to display object images. But displays normal images fine.

My Model

```
class News(models.Model):
title-----------
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
body------------
```

Template tag coding

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()
from ----.models import ---

def funct(num):
myobjects = News.objects.all()[:num]
return {'objects': myobjects}
register.inclusion_tag('news/template.html')(funct)
```

template coding

```
{% for object in objects %}
<li>{{ object.title }}</li>
<li><img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}images/{{ object.image }}" alt="image" /></li>
<li>{{ object.body }}</p></li>
{% endfor %}
```

This code outputs all the variable information such as title and body in a list however it does not display the associated image. I have tried numerous variations on this code with no success. This is strange because when an image is called from the image folder in the following manner

```
<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}images/star.jpg" />
```

Everything works fine. The problems occur when its a model image being called.
Any help fixing this issue is much appreciated

Comment: But is the image associated with the object actually present in the MEDIA_URL/images directory?

Comment: Yes, the  associated image is located in the MEDIA_URL/images directory

Comment: Can you add what actually appears in the rendered HTML?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the custom template tag. If you looked at the source for the rendered page, you would see that `{{ object.image }}` does not output the URL for the image. You need to use `{{ object.image.url }}`